# ListView.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is crashing app

Tags: java, android, listview, bluetooth

I am trying to populate a listView with paired bluetooth devices. I tried doing so with a ListView in my MainActivity and it worked perfectly. However, when I tried it with a ListView in a different activity it crashed the app. I basically want to populate a ListView in a pop-up dialog box.

Here is the code:

#### activity_device_list.xml (MainActivity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listDevicesMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### device_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.12"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Paired Devices"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listDevicesDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="395dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.38" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### DeviceList.java

```
package example.btmodule;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import static example.btmodule.R.layout.activity_device_list;

public class DeviceList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView devicelist;

    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_device_list);

        myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(myBluetooth == null)
        {
            //Show a mensag. that thedevice has no bluetooth adapter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.bluetooth_unavailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //finish apk
            finish();
        }
        else {
            if (myBluetooth.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                //Ask to the user turn the bluetooth on
                Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(turnBTon, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void pairedDevicesList()
    {
        pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDevicesDialog);

        if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
            {
                list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress()); //Get the device's name and the address
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_devices_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // menu item selection
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_connect:
                showDialog();
                pairedDevicesList();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    // show the dialog for connected devices
    private void showDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DeviceList.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.device_dialog, null);
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

If I change `devicelist` to `R.id.listDevicesMain` the code works perfectly fine.

Comment: what error are you getting can you add the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDevicesDialog);` - here you are looking for `listDevicesDialog` in activity layout, so `devicesList` becomes null. You should add `devicelist = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listDevicesDialog);` to showDialog() method and bring there rest of the operations related with searching for paired devices and setting adapter.

You can also call pairedDevicesList from showDialog and pass view where listDevicesDialog is:

```
private void pairedDevicesList(View dialogView)
{
    pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    devicelist = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.listDevicesDialog); 
...
}
// show the dialog for connected devices
private void showDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DeviceList.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.device_dialog, null);
    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
    pairedDevicesList(mView);
}
```

Comment: You are great. I knew it had something with me not looking for the dialog listview in the right place.. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you calling the wrong list view the id of the list view as you have given is

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listDevicesMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and you are trying to call the listview with id 
`devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDevicesDialog);`
hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I have another ListView called `listDevicesDialog` in device_dialog.xml which is what I am trying to call

Comment: Let me tell you something your list view must be in the activity layout but the only list view that is in your layout is this one so if you want to use that list view just change the layout that you are calling in the activity

Comment: Yeah I did not notice that at all.. That was my bad. Thanks anyways!